# Can I ignore certain visitors when using Goaccess?

Tags: nginx, spam, log-files, goaccess

I want to use `goaccess` to see how many real visitors my website is getting.
Unsurprisingly my logs are filled with traffic from bots so I'm looking for a way to filter that out.
In the interests of knowing what unwanted traffic continues to be sent I'd like to keep those logs too so that I can occasionally review it, like having a spam folder in my inbox.

I can see a couple of options:

1. Move the offending log lines to another location and continue to use `goaccess` as normal
2. Configure `goaccess` to ignore the unwanted requests

In both cases the challenge is identifying which are the unwanted log lines. **Does anyone know of the best tool to do that?**

For what it's worth, I'm using nginx and serving a static site, so I'm not worried about any of these attacks being successful.
I realise the filtering will never be perfect but I'm sure there's some low hanging fruit here to make significant improvements with minimal effort.